# Using Apache XAMPP on Windows 10 to create 1 Django website and one normal website

Tags: python, django, apache

I have created a Django protect that works perfectly fine on windows Apache with Xampp. However, if I try to create a virtual host for a non-Django website, it doesn't work.

If I then put my Django website into a virtual host it doesn't work, but then my **non-Django** website does work.

By doesn't work I mean it takes me to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS0a5.png

Here is all my code for my Django website inside a virtual host and my other non-project in a virtual host.

```
#Django Website
        <VirtualHost *:443 _default_:443 neostorm.us.to:443>
        ServerName neostorm.us.to
        ServerAlias neostorm.us.to
    Alias /static "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/static"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/neostorm/wsgi_windows.py" application-group=neostorm
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/neostorm">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "C:\xampp\apache\logs\neostorm_error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\xampp\apache\logs\neostorm_custom.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
#Non Django Website
    <VirtualHost *:443 mail.neostorm.us.to:443>
    ServerName mail.neostorm.us.to
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/webmail"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/webmail">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the png indicates that you are in neostorm.us.to:443 not in mail.neostorm.us.to:443 when the index is displayed. Are you sure there is not somewhere in your conf files (in an include?) another host definition that catches the request to neostorm.us.to:443 before your virtual host? There must be a root pointing to C:/xampp/htdocs/

Comment: @Razenstein Yes that was it, in my SSL config it had a virtual host, thank you for helping me fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was a virtual host inside the httpd-ssl.conf file. Simply delete the virtual host inside that file and create your virtual hosts inside your virtual host file or where ever you want it.

The reason you may see your index of files is because there is no index.html to open.

This is an example of a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/neostorm/webmail">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/example/example.com-chain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/example/example.com-key.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

If there is no index file inside that document root, you will see the index/ page.

Just a footnote, Options +Indexes tells your web server to show an index page like seen in the photo. Use Options -Indexes to prevent showing the index/ page, this is beneficial if you have a static folder.